# How to extract data from different matrix size

Tags: matlab

I have the following type of file:

```
 1: 0.0000    2: 0.0000    3: 0.0000    4: 0.0000    5: 0.0000    6: 0.0000   7: 0.0000    8: 0.0000    9: 0.0000   10: 0.0000   11: 0.0000   12: 0.0000   13: 0.0000
14: 0.0000   15: 0.0000   16: 0.0000   17: 0.0000   18: 0.0000   19: 0.0000
20: 0.0000   21: 0.0000   22: 0.0000   23: 0.0000   24: 0.0000   25: 0.0000   26: 0.0000   27: 0.0000   28: 0.0000   29: 0.0000   30: 0.0000   31: 0.0000   32: 0.0000
33: 0.0000   34: 0.0000   35: 0.0000   36: 0.0000   37: 0.0000   38: 0.0000
```

The file is separated in different lines, the numbers in line two belong to line one, the numbers in line four belong to line three, etc.

I need to extract the 0.000 numbers and make it into a matrix.

`fopen`,`load`,`importdata` cannot do that.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: So how would you want the matrix to look? Something like `[1,0.0000;2,0.0000;...` or maybe `[0.0000,0.0000,...`. Secondly: where does the lines terminate? The reason that I ask this is that I need to know how your data file is fomatted. Also, is this file format you uses standardized in some way? Btw, the correct notation is "read data from file".

Comment: I tried cleaning up your question, but I'm not 100% certain I got the layout of the file correct, since the indentation was all over the place.

Comment: How are you supposed to place these into a 2D matrix?  MATLAB does not support ragged matrices (each row has a different number of columns).  Would you like to retrieve individual arrays that store these numbers for each line?  You could store this into a cell array, where each element can store each row independently.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want to load each line as a separate 1D array, and store each of these arrays as an element inside a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).  If you want to store these lines inside a 2D matrix, then MATLAB is unable to do that for you as it doesn't have supported for [ragged matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irregular_matrix).  As a work around, you can use cell arrays as the contents inside cell arrays can be anything you want.  In our case, each element would be a 1D array of varying size.

What I would recommend you do first (as you have already tried) is to open up the file with [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html).  Next, what you can do is use [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to retrieve one line of the text file, and you would keep calling `fgetl` until you reach the end of your file, where `fgetl` has `-1` returned instead of a valid line in your file.  Note that what is returned is a string if it isn't -1.

Once you retrieve this string, the best way to parse through your string is to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (through [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)).  Regular expressions are used to find where certain patterns occur in a text string.  In your case, we are looking for a very specific pattern.  We are looking for occurrences of the following type:

```
[xx....xx](.)[xx....xx]
    ^      ^      ^
    1      2      3
```

You are looking for a pattern in your string that can be split up into three groups:

- Group #1 - At least one digit
- Group #2 - Zero or one decimal point
- Group #3 - At least one digit

As such, we can use regular expressions so that we can find these patterns in your string.  However, we also need to take the number followed by the `:` character into account, because the pattern I just described could match with the number that comes before the `:` character.  As such, we need to search for the entirety of the pattern in between the spaces.  Specifically:

```
[xx....xx]: [xx....xx](.)[xx....xx]
     ^    ^      ^     ^     ^
     1    2      3     4     5
```

You can see now that we can segment each unique pair of IDs and numbers into five groups:

- Group #1 - At least one digit
- Group #2 - A `:` character followed by a space
- Groups #3 - #5 - These are groups #1 to #3 from before

As such, once you read in your line, you'll want to get the values between groups #3 and #5 and put them into an array.  However, these values will be **strings**, and so you'll need to convert these into numbers to create your final numeric array.

Given that you read in a line from your text file stored in `s`, you would create your array of strings where each element is the string representation of the number like so:

```
c = regexp(s, '\d+: (\d+\.?\d+)', 'tokens');
```

Woah!  Looks pretty complicated right?  It actually isn't.  Let's go through this slowly.  The first input into `regexp` is the line you would like examined, which is one line from your text.  The second input is a string that contains a regular expression pattern.  You define regular expression syntax that describes the exact pattern of text you are looking for within this string.

As such, if you take a look at how I split up the string into 5 groups, this will help you parse through the pattern I created in an intuitive way.  Let's go through the groups again:

- Group #1 - `\d+` - We are searching for occurrences where we find at least one digit.  The `\d` means a digit, and the `+` means to look for at least **one** or **more** of these digits.
- Group #2 - `:` - We follow this by a colon (`:`), and after comes a space

Next, we use what is called a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) where we want to focus specifically on extracting out the next things that follow after the number and colon character.  Capture groups are surrounded by `()` characters.

- Group #3 - `\d+` - We seek to find those numbers that contain at least one digit
- Group #4 - `\.?` - After group #3, we need to follow this by searching for either zero or one dot.  The `?` characters means that you want to search for either zero or one occurrence.  In our case, we want to look for the dot.  Use `.` by itself implies a [wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character), and so if you want to search for the actual dot, you need to prepend this with `\`.  As such, we want to look for zero or one dots.
- Group #5 - `\d+` - Next, we follow this by searching for at least one digit at the end.

The significance of capture groups is that when you specify the `'tokens'` flag, we would thus return a cell array of matches in your string where each element in this cell array gives you the match for each capture group.  The regular expression syntax that we defined will return every single substring that is contained within this line that matches the above pattern.

*As such, what would happen here is that we would return a cell array of those numbers that come after each colon.*  Bear in mind that each string will be placed in a 1 x 1 cell array, so it's actually a nested cell array.  As such, what we're going to do is we're going to unpack out these cell entries using [`vertcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html), which then creates a 1D cell array of strings.  Now, because these are strings and you want to create a numeric array of elements, you need to finally use [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to achieve your final goal.  You would then place this into an element in your cell array.

In other words, you would have to do this:

```
e = str2double(vertcat(c{:}));
```

`e` would be the final numeric array for each line of text.  Therefore, your basic processing pipeline would be this:

1. Open up the file
2. Create output cell array
3. While we don't get -1 from `fgetl`

   - a. Read in a line
   - b. Parse with `regexp`
   - c. Create our numeric array
   - d. Store numeric array into output cell
4. Close the file

As such, your program is very simply this.  Let's say your text was stored in a file called `text.txt`.  Therefore:

```
%// Step #1
fid = fopen('text.txt');

%// Step #2
out = {};

%// Step #3
while true
    s = fgetl(fid); %// Step #3a
    if s == -1 %// Check if we need to get out - end of file
       break;
    end        
    c = regexp(s, '\d+: (\d+\.?\d+)', 'tokens'); %// Step #3b
    e = str2double(vertcat(c{:})); %// Step #3c
    out{end+1} = e; %// Step #3d
end

%// Step #4
fclose(fid);
```

---

`out` would contain the output cell array that houses all numbers per line.  Given your text example shown above, this is what we get when I run the above code:

```
>> out

out = 

    [13x1 double]    [6x1 double]    [13x1 double]    [6x1 double]

>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0



out{2} =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0



out{3} =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0



out{4} =

     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

---

If you compare the number of IDs for each line and the numbers after each colon, they match up, even though your example is artificial with a bunch of zeroes.